# Print lines between two patterns with multiple occurrence of 2nd pattern

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file like the following and I would like to print the lines between two given patterns PAT1 and PAT2.

```
1
2
PAT1
3    
4
PAT2
5
6
PAT2
7    
PAT2
8
9
PAT2
10
```

Here PAT1 occurs once, but PAT2 occurs multiple times. I would like to print the lines between PAT1 and the 3rd occurrence of PAT2

I use the below command to print between patterns which doesn't work in this case

```
awk '/PAT1/PAT2/'
```

I expect the below output

```
PAT1
3    
4
PAT2
5
6
PAT2
7    
PAT2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: can your input have multiple `PAT1..PAT2..PAT2..PAT2` to be extracted?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this works:

```
$ awk '/PAT1/,/PAT2/&&++c==3' file
PAT1
3 
4
PAT2
5
6
PAT2
7 
PAT2
```

See the comments on why it works.

Comment: Okay ... unexpected ... why does this work? I understand the syntax, but I do not see how this is fits the output.

Comment: @kvantour It was a pure _trial and this-once-not-an-error_.  :D Was there some related documentation?

Comment: It works, but I am not sure if it was a bug of gawk. in the man page this is written: `The pattern1, pattern2 form of an expression is called a range pattern.  It matches all input records starting with a record that matches pattern1, and continu‐    
       ing until a record that matches pattern2, inclusive.  It does not combine with any other sort of pattern expression.`  **It does not combine with any other sort of pattern expression**

Comment: It seems to work with gawk, mawk, bwk and Busybox awk.

Comment: The `,` operator has lowest precedence. So what you wrote is interpreted as `/PAT1/,(/PAT2/&&++c==3)`. This is exactly why the range-pattern works. The `end-pattern` only hits true one the third match of `PAT2`. Is that not amazing!

Comment: That makes sense, ie. `/PAT1/,(/PAT2/&&++c==3)` works, as opposed to `(/PAT1/,/PAT2/)&&++c==3` which gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
$cat file | awk 'BEGIN{foundPAT1=0; foundPAT2=0;} {if($0=="PAT1"){foundPAT1=1;next} if($0=="PAT2"){foundPAT2+=1;next} if(foundPAT2==3)exit; if(foundPAT1) print;}'
```

This will wait until it finds PAT1, then print until PAT2 is found 3 times and them exit the file.
This will exclude the PAT* from the output, you can include them by removing the "next" statements, which make awk jump to the next line.

Comment: why do you need cat? don't you know how to read a file with awk?

Comment: Sure you can do that (see the other answers for example), but maybe yo want to pass to awk the output from a previous command instead of a file, which "cat file | " represents here. It is the same really...

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed -E '/PAT1/!d;:A;N;/((.*PAT2){3})/!bA' infile
```